# How to execute Google social authentication using dj-rest-auth in React JS

Tags: reactjs, django, google-signin, dj-rest-auth

I am following this 2-part tutorial of using dj-rest-auth in django [part 1](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-build-google-social-login-in-django-rest-framework-and-nuxt-auth-and-refresh-its-jwt-token-752601d7a6f3) - [part 2](https://fadhilyaacob.medium.com/drf-nuxt-auth-social-login-part-2-48032aa3cb05) by: Mohamad Fadhil and I have no problem with the backend in Django but I was wondering if anyone could show me how to implement this on react instead of Nuxt?

Especially in the part where I can generate the `access_token` and the `code`?